# Selecting specific columns of one dataset based on values of a different dataset in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have one dataset with many columns

```
Yankees    Mets    Red Sox  Angels
6          5       2         3
12         8       4         3
7          0       1         3
```

and another dataset with some of those columns as row values as shown below

```
Teams

Yankees
Red Sox
```

And I want to select the columns that appear in my second dataset under teams so that the new dataset looks like this...

```
Yankees   Red Sox
6         2
12        4
7         1
```

How do I go about doing this in R? Especially if this is possible with dplyr.

Comment: Something like `df1 %>% select(any_of(df2$Teams))` should work.

Comment: Perfect, thank you